Highlight a row in a table when using RLS
I have a report on retail store performance. It uses RLS on tables [Store] and [Sales] so each store accessing the report only sees their data. However, I also show a league table of all stores based on a certain KPI. The league table is based on cut down versions of the above tables that do not have RLS. My question - how can I highlight (by formatting) the store running the report in the league table? Thanks.
I've tried adding an 'IsCurrentStore' column to the non RLS [Sales] table, and setting it to 1 if it matches a measure that stores the name of the store running the report, then using that to do some conditional formatting, but couldn't get this to work.
